# Where is the Crestfallen Saulden's grave?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I killed the Crestfallen Saulden for his ring, and now I want to ressurect him , but I don't know where his grave lies. Where is his grave? I think I've checked all places in Majula, but not anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

His grave does appear near where he was sitting.

The grave don't appear instantly, it can take from a couple of minutes to hours ( in-game ), just be patient and go back check once in a while.

Comment: Do you know where he's grave is, or does it differ from save to save?

Comment: As i mentioned, it should be close to where he was sitting. You can't miss it if it has appeared